# pptp is refusing traffic

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have setup a pptp (VPN) server on CentOS 6.5. I can connect, but unfortunately, when I try to load a page, it hangs on 'Connecting...' I have no idea what could cause this...

`tail /var/log/messages` returns:

`Apr 29 12:55:42 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1287]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=611860,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Apr 29 12:55:42 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1287]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
Apr 29 12:55:42 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1287]: CTRL: Client x.x.x.x control connection finished
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1296]: CTRL: Client x.x.x.x control connection started
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1296]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: peer from calling number x.x.x.x authorized
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: found interface eth0 for proxy arp
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: local  IP address 188.166.94.95
Apr 29 12:55:59 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: remote IP address 188.166.94.95
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: LCP terminated by peer (MPPE disabled)
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Connect time 0.4 minutes.
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Sent 0 bytes, received 22428 bytes.
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1296]: CTRL: EOF or bad error reading ctrl packet length.
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1296]: CTRL: couldn't read packet header (exit)
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1296]: CTRL: CTRL read failed
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Modem hangup
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Connection terminated.
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pppd[1297]: Exit.
Apr 29 12:56:20 ps-vpn001 pptpd[1296]: CTRL: Client x.x.x.x control connection finished`

Where `x.x.x.x` is my home IP.

My `options.pptpd`: http://pastebin.com/qiRv7six

Comment: Be aware PPTP is no longer being supported by several operating systems/distributions,  namely FreeBSD, MacOS Sierra, iOS 10 and pfSense, and more will follow.

Comment: It may be MTU issue. Check it by ping with big size packets.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach (and more painful) is to try and debug the problem, following http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml and enabling [debug logging](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-diagnosis.phtml#debug).

The second is to follow a [different guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp) to setup a PPTP VPN connection or preferably an OpenVPN guide like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-6):

Comment: I actually used DigitalOcean's tutorial; same problem.

Comment: For the majority of distributions you must load the nf_conntrack_proto_gre
and nf_conntrack_pptp kernel modules for certain PPTP/VPN servers. `sudo modprobe nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_conntrack_pptp` might help in this case. From your routers on both sides you might need to enable VPN/GRE passthrough. Try enable debugging logging for both sides (client & server) to understand the problem.